# Prove the formula for the foci of an ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I have summarized the question below:

> If the vertices of an ellipse centered at the origin are $(a,0),(-a,0),(0,b),$ and $(0,-b)$, and $a>b$, prove that for foci at $(\pm c,0)$, $c^2=a^2-b^2$.

I am guessing that I have to use the distance formula, which is $d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

Comment: The "sum of distances" must be $2a$ by looking at an endpoint of the major axis; add those focal distances up (assuming $a > b$ and that the foci are $(-c, 0)$ and $(c, 0)$). You get $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$ by looking at an endpoint on the minor axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With drawing ellipse shape with center at the origin and are $A(\pm a,0)$ and $B(0,\pm b)$ are vertices, find a symmetric shape and symmetric foci at $F(c,0)$ and $F'(-c,0)$. With definition for ellipse for exery point $X$ on ellipse $|XF|+|XF'|=2a$ so $|BF|+|BF'|=2a$ so $2\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=2a$ that concludes $c^2=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: How did you get the $2a$?

Comment: I said. By definition for ellipse .

Comment: Of course you may show it by $|AF|+|AF'|=2p$ for a $p$, but it is trivial conclude that $p=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Any point on the ellipse is such that $MF_1+MF_2=AF_1+AF_2=2a$ where $F_1,F_2$ are the foci and $A$ is the $(a,0)$ vertex. So let's write that for $B(0,b)$

$$\sqrt{c^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+b^2}=2a$$

This rewrites easily as $c^2+b^2=a^2$. QED